# 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am using Roslyn to parse a very basic WPF solution. I setup a diagnostics and found the following errors:

> MainWindow.xaml.cs(25,13): error CS0103: The name
>   'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
>
> error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable
>   for an entry point

Any idea how to solve this?

UPDATE

So I added a main method and now I am getting the following error:

> App.xaml.cs(20,17): error CS1061: 'App' does not contain a definition
>   for 'InitializeComponent' and no extension method
>   'InitializeComponent' accepting a first argument of type 'App' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> MainWindow.xaml.cs(25,13): error CS0103: The name
>   'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

Here is the main method

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        var app = new App();
        app.InitializeComponent();
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've given it an incomplete set of files to work with.

Comment: do you have a main method?

Comment: Well the App.xaml was set to build action ApplicationDefinition so the main should is automatically defined. If I change the build action to page I could define my own main method.

Comment: By any chance, have you renamed the MainWindow (or removed its namespace) in the xaml markup, without renaming it in the xaml.cs file?

Comment: No rename-ing just a basic wpf solution for testing

Comment: There is a lot more going on in a WPF project than just compiling the code.  Somewhat easy to see in plain WPF project that you build with the IDE.  Look in the obj subdirectory afterwards and note the .cs files there.  They contain the Main() entrypoint and the InitializeComponent glue.  MSBuild does that, it runs a code generator that takes the .xaml files as input.  Not so sure how you'd want to move ahead given this chicken-and-egg problem, it is not obvious why you'd want to use Roslyn.  Telling Roslyn about those .cs files is the workaround.

Comment: I updated my question with more error code. I would assume that Roslyn would handle an out of the box unchanged hello world wpf application?

Comment: Please post your main method

Comment: @Abhiverma see main method in question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are loading this solution with code similar to the following:

```
var ws = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var solution = await ws.OpenSolutionAsync(path);
```

Then the problem is that you are not analyzing the code that should be generated from your .xaml files. This can be solved by changing the above code to:

```
var properties = new Dictionary<string, string> { ["DesignTimeBuild"] = "true" };
var ws = MSBuildWorkspace.Create(properties);
var solution = await ws.OpenSolutionAsync(path);
```

For more information, see also https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2779